# Is a graph database (Neo4j, for example) a feasible solution for a collaborative filtering (CF) recommender?

Tags: database, graph, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

My recommender is intended to a site news, to recommend news, videos, and audios to the users.

The characteristics of the website in production are the following:
The average traffic durign a day is:

- 14.000.000 viewd pages
- 2.000.000 unique visitors
- ¿¿??? concurrent users

The current amount of assets is:

- Videos: 500.000
- Audios: 400.000
- News: 200.000

The desired characteristics of the recommender are the following:

- Memory-based neighbourhood-based CF: no model-based (no training, no matrix, etc.)
- Near realtime response time: when a recommendation request for a user arrives, the system
  allways must response in milliseconds.
- Near realtime "recalculations": when an "asset viewed" arrives to the system, that
  information must be taken into account "immediately" for all user recommendations.
- To calculate a user recommendation, it is taken into account:

  - The last (1 hour) viewed assets of the user.
  - All the historical (from the beginning of recording statistics to now) visions of the other users.

How would be comparatively the computation resouces needed for a graph based solution
with the needed for a Spark ALS (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html)
solution?

Anybody have reliable information about websites with that workload that use that kind
of recommender?